При стрельбе с использованием Raycast луч попадает в персонажа
При стрельбе под ноги персонажа с использованием Raycast луч попадает в персонажа. Не понимаю из-за чего так и как это исправить
RaycastHit hit;

if (Physics.Raycast(maimCamera.transform.position, maimCamera.transform.forward, out hit, range))
{
    Debug.Log("попал " + hit.collider);
    Zombi zombi = hit.transform.GetComponent<Zombi>();
    if (zombi != null)
    {
        zombi.TakeDamage(damagePlayer);
    }

    if (hit.rigidbody != null)
    {
        hit.rigidbody.AddForce(-hit.normal * force);
    }
}


В метод Physics.Raycast можно передать маску, с какими коллайдерами луч может сталкиваться, а с какими нет, см. документацию: (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) Гугли "unity raycast маска"
